# Texture painting doesnt work as intended

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Im new to blender and wanted to try making the famous donut. But when i started working on texture painting i came across a problem. When I tried painting the texture, i couldnt paint the 3d donut because my drawings were random and not where i wanted them to be. What could be the problem here?

[image: The PROBLEM]

Answer (score 0):

If your texture painting isn't working right its probably because of your mesh. I had to go to *Edit Mode* and select all vertices. Then I just simply go to *Mesh > Normals* menu and then click on *Recalculate Outside*.